# JavaScript to confirm before BPF movement not working in Dynamics 365 CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

I need help on the below JavaScript; everything is working fine except when the user selects the next stage, Confirm Dialog prompt for confirmation, but when the user clicks on the OK button in the dialog box, this action does not move to the next stage. Simply close the dialog box. If anyone can help me with this?

```
function onLoad(executionContext) {
  var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
  var process = formContext.data.process;        

  //handles changes to the BPF before they actually occur
  process.addOnPreStageChange(myProcessStateOnPreChange);
} 

function myProcessStateOnPreChange(executionContext) {
  var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
  var process = formContext.data.process;
  var eventArgs = executionContext.getEventArgs();

  var currentStageId = process.getActiveStage().getId();
  var nextStageId = process.getSelectedStage().getId();

  //dont allow to go back using the set active button
  if (currentStageId != nextStageId) {
    eventArgs.preventDefault();
    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("You cannot set completed stage as Active.")
    return;
  }        
      
  if (eventArgs._direction === 1) //backwards
  {            
    //logic based upon the BPF going to the previous Stage.
    eventArgs.preventDefault();
      var alertStrings = { cancelButtonLabel: "Cancel", confirmButtonLabel: "OK", text: "Backward stage movement is not allowed", title: "Warning" };
      var alertOptions = { height: 120, width: 260 };
      Xrm.Navigation.openAlertDialog(alertStrings, alertOptions);
    return;
  }

  //otherwise forward
  // logic based upon the BPF going to the next Stage.
  if (eventArgs._direction === -1) 
  {   eventArgs.preventDefault(); 
    var confirmStrings = { 
        cancelButtonLabel: "Cancel", 
        confirmButtonLabel: "OK", 
        text: "Are you sure you want to move forward in the BPF?", 
        title: "Confirm BPF Movement" 
    };
    var confirmOptions = { height: 120, width: 260 };
    Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog(confirmStrings, confirmOptions).then(function(success) {
        if (success.confirmed) {
            formContext.data.process.moveNext();
            console.log("BPF movement confirmed");
        } else 
        {
            console.log("BPF movement cancelled");
        }
    });
  }
  //Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Warning: You cannot undo this movement.")
}
```

BPF in Dynamics 365 CRM is supposed to move to the next stage after confirming the dialog prompt and the user clicks on the OK button

Comment: the property `confirmed` does not exist in the `success` boolean. `if (success.confirmed)`  is just `if(success)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-navigation/openalertdialog#example

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that the `moveNext()` and `movePrevious()` functions both

- <s>require callbacks (not present in your code example)</s>
- trigger the `OnStageChange` method

I think you need to maintain your own state outside of the eventhandler. Then you can determine whether your handler is running from a user-click, or the default callback trigger.

Something like this is working for me

**NOTE**: I ran this code in the console, so there are some differences to how I added the event handler (e.g. using `Xrm.Page`)

```
var customStageEventInProgress = false;
Xrm.Page.data.process.addOnPreStageChange(myProcessStateOnPreChange);

function myProcessStateOnPreChange(executionContext) {
    if (customStageEventInProgress === true) { 
        // if my custom event is in progress then
        //    - don't re-execute custom logic
        //    - don't preventDefault 
        return; 
    }
    customStageEventInProgress = true;

    const direction = executionContext.getEventArgs().getDirection();
    if (direction === 'Next') {
        // I'm only running this on moveNext
        // I was going backwards quite a lot to test 
        executionContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();

        const confirmStrings = { 
            cancelButtonLabel: 'Cancel', 
            confirmButtonLabel: 'OK', 
            text: 'Are you sure you want to move forward in the BPF?', 
            title: 'Confirm BPF Movement' 
        };
        const confirmOptions = { height: 120, width: 260 };
        Xrm.Navigation.openConfirmDialog(confirmStrings, confirmOptions).then(function (choice) {
            if (choice.confirmed) {
                console.log('BPF movement confirmed');
                Xrm.Page.data.process.moveNext(function (status) { 
                    customStageEventInProgress = false;
                });
            } 
            else {
                console.log('BPF movement cancelled');
                customStageEventInProgress = false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```